# HTTP Status 404 - /SchoolSchedule/ - Eclipse tutorial

Tags: eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

I am a newbie on web app development and learning Eclipse with Tomcat7.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/SchoolSchedule/BuildingAScheduleWebApp.html) but keep getting `HTTP Status 404` -/SchoolSchedule
there is no compiling error.

Can you help to point out what the problem is.

Here is the servlet code:

```
package org.eclipse.wtp.sample.classschedule;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/ScheduleServlet"})
public class ScheduleServlet extends HttpServlet {

....
                                                                                       getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/SchoolSchedule.jsp").forward(req, resp);
            //getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/SchoolSchedule.jsp").forward(req, resp);; 

            doPost(req, resp);
    }

}
```

And the JSP page has FORM action="/SchoolSchedule/SchoolSchedule.jsp" method="post"

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert in "Servlets" and so far, the tutorial looks good (maybe it is not updated at all since it is using Java 1.4).

I believe you're inside `doPost` or `doGet` method, if not, for sure you have the `req` and `resp` variables which are the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse respectively.

Then... I would suggest to replace your commented line

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/SchoolSchedule.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

by this one:

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("/schoolSchedule.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

Let me know if this works for you or helps you somehow.

Happy coding!

Comment: I also found that my servlet is not registered at all with the project. I have now corrected it and still no good...will have to investigate more.

Comment: By registering you mean register your servlet in web.xml file? Since you're using Servlet 3.0, no need to do that at all if you are using a compatible container. What version of Java are you using? and what is your server, maybe Tomcat?